# Resource not found in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am creating a web application in Eclipse IDE. My project was running fine. Once I did clean project and after that when I am trying to run it its throwing error

> resource not found

Also there is a red exclamation mark in front of the project name.

Comment: Have you checked your build path?

Comment: what to look for in build path?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do few things trying to fix that.

First of all. Make a refresh. press F5 on the very first folder of the project.

Now try to build again the project ctrl - B (ord cmd B in mac).

then find an error in a class, find the resource that is giving you problem (maybe a class) and then try to go to that class, right click, build path > add to build path.

Do it with every class giving you problem

if the problem is still there try a again to rebuild.

if the problem is not resolved, please comment this answer with a screenshot and I will help you better (hope)